# How to use the xml setting in a view of a activity?

Tags: android, view

I want to show two views in one activity. If I clicked on button in the first view I want to see the second and other way round. 
The views should not have the same size as the screen so I want e.g. to center it, like you see in first.xml.

But if I add the views with

```
addContentView(mFirstView, new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
```

the views are not centered. They are shown at top left.

How can I use the xml settings to e.g. center it?

**first.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:background="@drawable/background"
android:layout_gravity="center"
android:minWidth="100dp"
android:minHeight="100dp"
android:paddingBottom="5dp"
>

<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/head" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">           

    <ImageButton android:id="@+id/first_button"
    android:src="@drawable/show_second"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@null" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**second.xml** same as first.xml but with

```
<ImageButton android:id="@+id/second_button"
     android:src="@drawable/show_first"
    ... />
```

**ShowMe.java**

```
public class ShowMe extends Activity {

View mFirstView = null;
View mSecondView = null;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);        

    initFirstLayout();
    initSecondLayout();
    showFirst();        
}

private void initFirstLayout() {

    LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
    mFirstView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.first, null);

    getWindow().addContentView(mFirstView, new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

    ImageButton firstButton = (ImageButton)mMaxiView.findViewById(R.id.first_button);
    firstButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            ShowMe.this.showSecond();
        }
    });
}

private void initSecondLayout() {
// like initMaxiLayout()
}

private void showFirst() {
    mSecondView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    mFirstView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}

private void showSecond() {
    mFirstView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    mSecondView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}}
```

Hope someone can help.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use `setContentView(R.layout.yourlayout)`? I believe the new `LayoutParams` you're passing in `addContentView()` are overriding those you defined in xml.

Moreover, `ViewGroup.LayoutParams` lacks the layout gravity setting, so you would have to use the right one for the layout you're going to add the view to (I suspect it's a `FrameLayout`, you can check with Hierarchy Viewer). This is also a general rule to follow. When using methods that take layout resources as arguments this is automatic (they might ask for the intended parent).

With this consideration in mind, you could set your layout params with:

```
FrameLayout.LayoutParams lp = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(/* wrap wrap */);
lp.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);

addContentView(mYourView, lp);
```

But I would recommend `setContentView()` if you have no particular needs.

**EDIT**

I mean that you create a layout like:

~~~`/res/layout/main.xml`~~~

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="....."
    android:id="@+id/mainLayout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>
```

then in your `onCreate()` or `init...Layout()`:

```
setContentView(R.layout.main);
FrameLayout mainLayout = (FrameLayout)findViewById(R.id.mainLayout);

// this version of inflate() will automatically attach the view to the
// specified viewgroup.
mFirstView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.first, mainLayout, true);
```

this will keep the layout params from xml, because it knows what kind it needs. See [reference](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/LayoutInflater.html#inflate%28int,%20android.view.ViewGroup,%20boolean%29).

Comment: If I use setContentView() can I get this view to save it in mFirstView/mSecondView?
Otherwise I have to initialize (In my real code is more as a button in it) the two views after each call of setContentView, or?

In a other case I do setContentView() with a (google)mapView and want to add these two views which not full overlap the mapview. I think in this case I can not use setContentView(), or?

If I do not use setContentView() is there are no way to use the layout which is already defined in the xml? So that I do not have to set it again in code like "lp.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER)"?

Comment: @AnWi: uhm, it seems you do have particular needs indeed. With `setContentView()` you would have to initialize the views, because it inflates them directly from xml. I suggest inflating them with `LayoutInflater` into your `mFirstView`/`mSecondView`, and have a main `FrameLayout` with an id set with `setContentView()`, so you grab it with `findViewById()` and can add/remove views in a more flexible way.

Comment: @bigstones     I'm not realy understands you: what do you mean with a main FrameLayout? (Do you mean the mapView in my case and two other xml's?) Should I add the views with the `FrameLayout.LayoutParams` anyway or is there a way to adopt the xml layout?

Comment: @bigstones it works! Thanks! And sorry for my terrible english

Comment: @AnWi: you're welcome, remember that you can accept answers to thank people ;) (click the green tick mark next to the question, under the vote)